# Indexing/tokenizing nested JSON with elasticsearch

Tags: json, indexing, elasticsearch

Say I have the following JSON object

```
{
  "name" : "Hulk",
  "traits" : {
    "colour" : "green",
    "patience" : "none"
  }
}
```

I want to be able to search using a term like `"traits:patience"`. What is the best approach?

To make things clearer (hopefully), here is another example, say I have the following object

```
{
  "characters": {
    "hulk": {
      "strength": 100,
      "specialty": "smash"
    },
    "cyclops": {
      "strength": 25,
      "specialty": "lasers"
    }
  }
}
```

Ideally, I want to be able to search using the term `hulk:specialty` and get back `smash`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

To reference nested fields use the '.'-notation:

```
POST /<index-name>/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "traits.patience": "none"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout multi fields in elasticsearch http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#_multi_fields_3